# How to configure a sites-available entry for mediawiki on RPi behind firewall?

Tags: apache2, mediawiki

I am trying to define a sites-available .conf entry for a mediawiki scratch installation on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian in my local network (behind the firewall). No DNS or domain name associated with it. No matter how I configure it for Apache 2 it comes back with a 500 error. Does anyone have a simple sample mediawiki.conf file that I can use to define the site? The local IP is 10.0.0.67.

Comment: Generally your web server will record why it generates an error in an error log. Use that to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the error log but in media-error_log. It appears the mediawiki configuration page(s) does not overwrite the local settings file. Instead, it just appends to the end. This causes only the default config to be read (or whatever was there). I edited it to take out everything except the last config that was appended and the site came right up.